# How to stop showing message from other if else

Tags: c++

Hi as you can see im clearly new to c++. im supposed to write a program that inputs a grade and then displays pass if score is greater than or equal to 50 and fail otherwise. Also if the score is less the 0 or greater than 100 it is supposed to display an error message. However whenever I enter a score that is greater than 100 or less than 0, it displays Pass/ Fail, as well as the error message. I need it to only display the error message if it is greater than 100 or less than 0. This is what i've got so far.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int score;

    cout << "Please enter the score." << endl;
    cin >> score;

    if (score > 100)
        cout << "Invalid Score." << endl;

    if (score < 0)
        cout << "Invalid Score.";

    if (score >= 50)
        cout << "Pass" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Fail." << endl;
        cout << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Stylistic issue: don't indent `cout << endl;` if it doesn't belong to the `else` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Both `score > 100` and `score < 0` do the same thing, so you can combine them into one `if` statement with the logical-or operator `||`:

```
if( score > 100 || score < 0 )
    cout << "Invalid Score." << endl;
```

Then, you can use `else if` for your other conditions:

```
if( score > 100 || score < 0 )
    cout << "Invalid Score." << endl;
else if( score >= 50 )
    cout << "Pass" << endl;
else
    cout << "Fail." << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

if it meets one of the fail criteria you don't want to continue checking the other if cases.  So use the else case for everything.

```
int main()    
{    
    int score;

    cout << "Please enter the score." << endl;
    cin >> score;

    if (score > 100)
       cout << "Invalid Score." << endl;

    else if (score < 0)
        cout << "Invalid Score.";

    else if (score >= 50)
        cout << "Pass" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Fail." << endl;
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**hint** use else-if statements. These check if the first statement doesn't work, then it checks whether the next one will work, and if it doesn't, nothing runs.